# Japanse characters unreadable

Tags: unicode, cjk

I am working on my thesis and got acces to a database that was used by Japanese scientists. They included some readme files, but the text that was supposed to be in Japanese, is displayed in characters like these:

ÉRÅ[ÉqÅ[Ç…É~ÉãÉNÇì¸ÇÍÇ‹Ç∑Ç©ÅB

I've tried everything to convert them to Japanese characters, but I can't get it right. De database is from 1999, maybe that makes it harder to convert it?

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Show the [mcve] you are using to fetch the data. To answer this we will need to know the kind of DB, and probably the schema definition of the columns you are fetching this data from. Also, consider _how_ you are printing these strings out. The data can be interpreted in a number of ways, and the act of printing a string makes assumptions about that, and then the actual font used also has to have those glyphs. What we see here looks like the former, where whatever is printing this stuff thinks it is supposed to be interpreted as Latin characters.

Comment: That all being said, this is probably more suited for research on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ unless _maybe_ this is specifically about some code you have written that accesses this data through a DB driver.

Comment: Wait. Are you have trouble showing the text from the database, or from the README? [Edit] the question and make that clear. But, really, this feels like it ought to be researched over on DBA SE.

Comment: What is this “everything” you’ve tried? In a nutshell, you need to interpret the file in the correct encoding. E.g. tell the text editor you’re using to open the file to open it using the correct encoding. There are only half a dozen or so *commonly* used Japanese encodings, just try them all.

Comment: Maybe I can work the other direction.  Do you have the Japanese that the string should represent?

Answer (score 0):

So you have a text file, but with these strange characters ? Does your text editor allow you to change the page encoding ?

For exemple, in Atom, once your text file is open, you can switch the page encoding using the status bar: Atom knows (but perhaps it is inherited from the host system) Shift JIS, CP 932 and EUC-JP, which seem to be all related to japanese character encoding.

Maybe you can find helpful details from [this page](https://www.sljfaq.org/afaq/encodings.html) ?

But even once done, I guess you have to find out a native speaker in order to tell you if the results make sense...

Comment: Yes,  "Does your text editor allow you to change the page encoding?" this worked! In bbEdit, it is possible to change the encoding. Saving the text with the different encoding gives me back the Japanese characters. Thanks for the hint!